# Blank screen onResume() after gl Context destruction, Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-ndk, glsurfaceview

For our game on Android OS we have been using the ndk mainly, to write our game and a thin Java wrapper so than we can support all devices with gles 2.0 hardware.

Our implementation is pretty standard, using the overrides of GLSurfaceView we:
* create/resume the c++ part of the game onSurfaceChanged(),
* render onDrawFrame(),
* inform the engine about lost gl Context at destroyContex() which usually occurs when the app pauses or gets destructed.

When the gl context gets recreated (when resuming - onSurfaceChanged()) we pass back the information to the game and reload all gl resources back in. During the time between onSurfaceChanged() and the first onDrawFrame though the screen is black but I have noticed quite a few 3D games that dont have this kind of a problem (i.e Gun Bros), they also dont seem to reload their resources (unless they have everything memory and quickly load them back in).

Any info on why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but if you dump the screen with glReadPixels or similar on destroyContext(), and then the first thing you do on onSurfaceChanged() is to upload that and draw, you will show the user a valid image before your first onDrawFrame.

Comment: Unfortunately `onDestroyContext` is called _after_ the context has been destroyed and so any gl calls constitutes an error at that point. I am starting to think that everybody is using a modified GLSurfaceView, which in the end proved easy enough to do; but in the end is a hack which might trigger problems down the line.